# access host file system and bash from dockerized Jenkins

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have environment with running MySQL, asp.net core and Jenkins containers (using docker-compose). I want to use my Jenkins container to create a pipeline which pulls my asp.net core app from GitHub and rebuilds the corresponding container(my running asp.net core container).

I create a pipeline to pull my repo but I noticed that repository was pulled into Jenkins container instead of host file system

also I don't know how to rebuild my asp.net core image from Jenkins pipeline and run it again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As far as *Docker* goes, your container has access to whatever paths you give it access to. *Jenkins* is another matter entirely and I wouldn't want to deal with it if I could possibly avoid it.